# Jest memory leak when using mongodb-memory-server

Tags: mongodb, jestjs, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

I had noticed that the the contexts of the setup file are kept around when `mongodb-memory-server` is in use, but i cannot figure out exactly why, the only clue i have found is that seemingly jest keeps the contexts around (via a lower property of `Symbol(JEST_STATE_SYMBOL)`?)

repro repository: https://github.com/hasezoey/jest-mem-leak

- `master`: 38 MB -> 41 MB if `--inspect-brk` is used, 37 -> 71 MB if `--inspect-brk` is *not* used
- `advanced`: 52 MB -> 104 MB (both with and without `--inspect-brk`)

(MB for the branches are the logged MB heap usage by jest)

[image: example pic]

The snapshot was taken after the jest message `Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...` and similar results can be observed taking a snapshot mid-test.
The used command is `node --inspect-brk --expose-gc ./node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand --logHeapUsage`

---

I already tried:

- to remove the `setInterval` from `get-port` (used by `mongodb-memory-server`) which reduces the memory leak, which in turn reduces the (chrome) heap snapshots from 229MB (with the interval) to 67 MB (without the interval), but one context is still around (instead of many) and the reported heap size by jest is steady across all tests (~57MB).

  [for reference, commenting out this section in `get-port`](https://github.com/sindresorhus/get-port/blob/a9b445ea0afbd75b81b7b9011c896e111e2d4aee/index.js#L50-L60)

  - instead of straight-up commenting-out the code, i also tried adding a `clearInterval(interval)` directly after the mentioned block, which seems to have a similar effect, but less steady heap-usage (instead of steady 57MB, it grows from 52MB to 55MB)
- setting the variable `mongoServer` (or `mongoServer._instanceInfo`) in `setup.js` to `undefined`, which does not help.

[original issue](https://github.com/nodkz/mongodb-memory-server/issues/776)